# Pass a view from react-native to native Objective-c code over the bridge

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to pass view reference from react-native to native objective-c code? I need this to modify my view using native code.

Comment: Did you find out an answer to this? I'm looking to do a similar thing

Comment: Also looking for the answer to this question. Or if there's at least a best practice where you look up the View by ID or something.